# How can I test my python module without installing it

Tags: python, testing

I'm in the process of redesigning/refactoring my Python quantum chemistry package (pyquante). One of the things I don't like about the existing release is that I have to install the package to run the test suite. That is, the test suite has statements like `from PyQuante import SCF`, and, of course, this PyQuante could refer to the installed version or a local version.

I know about virtualenv, and realize this is an option for me. But I was wondering whether anything else might be appropriate. In the past I've hacked `sys.path` for things like this, and have been told by better Python programmers that I shouldn't ever to this.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can do this? The point is that I want to test the current version of the code without installing it.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can see through my babbling and offer suggestions!

Comment: May I ask an explanation, why you shouldn't "hack" `sys.path`?

Comment: Afaik, with setupstools you can use `develop` instead of `install` to install a linked version which points to your development project. Thus no need to ever reinstall it.

Comment: @khackik it can lead to things not being present, and cause things to break. it's mainly because people tend to forget what they did to sys.path and continue business as usual. if your careful, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a proper package for your stuff and use

```
python setup.py develop
```

to make it a proper dev-package.

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048754/548039
- http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode

Answer (score 8):

I would honestly insist on using ***virtualenv***, its designed for this exact reason in mind. very small overhead, and if you ever mess up just delete directory. I am sure as you grow, things won't be as simple as they are now for your current situation. Take it as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Yes I agree with this. Here's an introduction : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490351/switch-between-python-versions-as-non-root/13490980#13490980. And here the official web site : http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Altering `sys.path` much in production environment may be unwise. Altering it for testing is usually OK.

If you don't want to tinker with the variable from `sys`, use an environment variable named `PYTHONPATH`, it's a clean and documented way.

Comment: At program startup by default, the first item of `sys.path`, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. This means that all you need to do is just put your test suite in the same directory that the module it tests is in and `import`ing it will work.