# Switch between Python versions as non root

Tags: python

I just installed Python 2.7 in our server, they had 2.4 installed before hand.

After I built the new version, my path is still pointing to the old version of python, do you know an easy way to change this.

I do not have sudo permissions nor root access.

Comment: [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), and not merely because you want to use different versions of python... imagine the need to install new modules after you get your interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are on the server and don't have root permissions, the best choice for you is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/)

Build Python 2.7, for example, as following:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=~/mydir
$ make
$ make install
```

Download [`virtualen.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py) file and run:

```
$ ~/mydir/bin/python virtualenv.py my_environment
```

This will create an isolated Python 2.7 environment for you inside `my_environment` directory.

To activate it run `source my_environment/bin/activate` and that's it. Now `python` executable will be your Python 2.7. Additionally you will have `pip` installed and thus can easily install any additional libraries into your environment.

Comment: Sourcing `activate` is for the current session only. Other answers mention how to use `.profile` or similar to make such settings persistent.

Comment: The point here is that you can have multiple environments, so when you login to remote shell, you can choose which one to activate. But I agree that you should also put `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/install/dir/bin` into `.bashrc` or something to easy access Python 2.7 executable outside of virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked for me. To have it work fine I had to do some additional operations : 
`$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/mydir/lib` to enable finding shared library `libpython2.7.so.1.0` (as I configured with option `--enable-shared`).

Then added the command above plus `source my_environment/bin/activate` to my `.bashrc` to have everything persistent.

Finally `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Also, added `alias python=python2.7` to the .bashrc, to keep consistency while running a script (as my system was still calling the 2.6.6 when calling python).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check your `~/.profile` and your shells config files (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash) for any `export $PATH=` (or `PYTHONPATH`, depending on what you're referring to exactly) directives containing the offending path. If there are some, change them and relogin. That should fix your problem.

If it doesn't, talk to your admin. If that doesn't help either, you can do the following. In your shell, run (may substitute `PATH` with `PYTHONPATH`, depending on what you really need):

```
echo $PATH
```

copy the output and modify it according to your needs. Then *open another shell* and run (remember the substitution):

```
export PATH="whatever you copied before"
```

check that everything is fine (i.e. that you can still call all applications you need and that your path is adapted accordingly). If that's the case, add the command to your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your environment is Linux, Unix or something similar.

If your problem is the `PATH` environment variable not pointing at the correct binary, then modify that `PATH`: make it include a given directory, e.g. `~/bin`, by executing `PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}` from one of your profile files, e.g. `~/.profile`. Make sure to create that directory, and have it contain a symlink named `python` pointing to the correct version of Python.

This won't help for scripts which have a hardcoded path, e.g. start with `#!/usr/bin/python`. When you call these directly from the command line, you can simply call the interpreter (i.e. `python`) instead, passing the name of the script as an argument: `python /path/to/script.py`. You can even use the python version you want in its place, i.e. `python2.7 /path/to/script.py`.

You might also turn this whole sequence into a script in your `~/bin` directory, e.g. have `~/bin/foo` contain the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ${HOME}/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/foo
```

Don't forget to `chmod -x ~/bin/foo` the file. You get an executable shell script which on your `PATH` comes before the default version installed on your system. The script will then call that default version, using a very specific interpreter. So now you can simply type the short name, and have the official script executed by your desired python version.

It might happen that some other script attempt to execute a given python script using its absolute path name. In that case, no modification of the `PATH` will help. You'll have to modify the first line of the script in question to read e.g. to `#!/usr/bin/env python`. If you cannot control those scripts, you are in trouble, and will need more advanced hacks to tweak the system into doing something it usually wouldn't do. `LD_PRELOAD` comes to mind.

Comment: For script with `#!/usr/bin/python`, simply pass it directly to the interpreter `python27 script`

Comment: @Dikei, you're right, that's a good solution if you're directly calling the scripts. Things only become troublesome if scripts call other scripts or similar. Will edit my answer to take this into account.