# Cython: Trying to wrap SFML Window; getting "ImportError: No module named 'ExprNodes'"

Tags: cython

sfml.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "SFML/Window.hpp" namespace "sf":

    cdef cppclass VideoMode:
        VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int) except +

    cdef cppclass Window:
        Window(VideoMode, String) except + 
        void display()
```

display.pyx:

```
cimport sfml

cdef class Window:

    cdef sfml.Window* _this

    def __cinit__(self, unsigned int width, unsigned int height):

        self._this = new sfml.Window(sfml.VideoMode(width, height), "title")

    def __dealloc__(self):

        del self._this

    def display(self):

        self._this.display()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [
        Extension("display", ["display.pyx"],
        language='c++',
        libraries=["sfml-system", "sfml-window"])
    ]
)
```

The error when running `python setup.py build`:

```
running build
running build_ext
cythoning display.pyx to display.cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    libraries=["sfml-system", "sfml-window"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 163, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 354, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 170, in build_extensions
    ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 317, in cython_sources
    full_module_name=module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 608, in compile
    return compile_single(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 549, in compile_single
    return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 386, in run_pipeline
    from . import Pipeline
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Pipeline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .Visitor import CythonTransform
  File "Visitor.py", line 10, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor (/build/src/Cython-0.19/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.c:15987)
ImportError: No module named 'ExprNodes'
```

Apparently, it can't find something called 'ExprNodes', but I don't think that my Cython installation is broken, because [I managed to successfully wrap a different C++ library some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383792/cython-invalid-operand-types-for-btvector3-btvector3), and I didn't run into this problem.

I'm using Cython 0.19.

I would appreciate any help/insight that you could offer.

Thanks.

Comment: Cython site args to be compatible with python 2.4 to 3.3, but I recently encountered similar issues while compiling an extension with 2.6.6 (+ Cython 0.18). Switching to 2.7.5 fixed it. So have you tried an earlier version of python 3.X ?

Note : switching between Python versions can be quite easy depending on the plateform : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490351/switch-between-python-versions-as-non-root/13490980#13490980

Comment: By the way, does anyone has pointer(s) on the real compatibilities of Cython's versions ?

Comment: ExprNodes is one of core Cython modules. Your Cython installation (or environment) _is_ broken.

Comment: @Galgauth: I would much rather figure out the bug, and fix it, then revert back to an old version. I mean, this is something that would have to be done sooner or later, so it might as well be sooner. Right?

Comment: @Nikita Namekin: Well, it's not a missing file. I mean, I can see ExprNodes.py in /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/. It's there. Also, as noted, I was able to wrap a different C++ lib before (with the same exact setup), and I didn't encounter any problems. So, I don't see how you can be so sure, but if it's really true, than I would like to know the specifics: How exactly is broken, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking more closely at the traceback, I see that Cython fails inside it's own compiled code. It may be a bug indeed, sorry for missing it the first time.

What can you do:

- Create a clean virtualenv, install Cython there and check if it works. (Version 0.19.1 is the latest).
- Create another virtualenv, but this time install Cython using `python setup.py install --no-cython-compile`.

If either of these fails, please post your *detailed* configuration (linux distro and version, python version, gcc version, etc.) to the cython-devel mailing list.

BTW does your old successful project still compile?

Comment: The first virtualenv resulted in the same error. The second virtualenv gave me a more detailed traceback, which was in a file called math.py, which was actually in the same directory as display.pyx. I renamed the file to m_math.py and then tried again, which worked fine (I have other problems now, but at least Cython works). So, basically, cython just sucked in the local math.py file ... I don't know if that's a bug, but it was a problem in this case. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @NikitaNemkin I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.