# Install package on multiple python versions using easy_insatll

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install a python package using `easy_install`. There are several python versions installed.
This causes the package to be installed on python2.7, whereas I want it to be installed on python2.4.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Edit:

I already have tried `easy_install-2.4`. I get `-bash: easy_install-2.4: command not found`

Comment: Changing your `PYTHONHOME` to the targeted version doesn't help ?

Comment: what OS do you use? it heavily depends on our operation system environment.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a particularly helpful answer, but have you tried virtualenv? It'll help you avoid issues like this in the future.

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: True, but as far as I understood the question, he wants to use what is already in place. Anyway http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678267/1715716 for intro to virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without providing us operation system information you use. For example in OSX, `easy_install` has it's own versions, I just type `easy_install[tab][tab]` to get all available version of `easy_install`.

In OSX and debian and redhat I've got these:

- easy_install
- easy_install-2.5
- easy_install-2.6
- easy_install-2.7

For each python version you've got your own package. For example if this would be pip there's packages in osx:

- py27-pip
- py24-pip
- py31-pip

`easy_install` probably build-in within python so it's should go per python version. and default one will be, the one which python version is set to default in your environment.

Comment: I'm using Suse 10. I see that I have easy_install, easy_install-2.7. No easy_install-2.4. What do I do next?

Comment: Now you need to install it http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#installing-easy-install