# Python setup.py develop vs install

Tags: python, setuptools

Two options in setup.py `develop` and `install` are confusing me. According to this [site](http://www.siafoo.net/article/77#install-vs-develop), using `develop` creates a special link to site-packages directory.

People have suggested that I use `python setup.py install` for a fresh installation and `python setup.py develop` after any changes have been made to the setup file.

Can anyone shed some light on the usage of these commands?

Comment: if you are looking for an example of how to call `pip install -e` without `.` you can do for example: `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/` where `path/src` is the path to the src of the project where `setup.py` is at. This is a useful related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install

Answer (score 653, accepted):

`python setup.py install` is used to install (typically third party) packages that you're not going to develop/modify/debug yourself.

For your own stuff, you want to first install your package and then be able to frequently edit the code *without* having to re-install the package every time — and that is exactly what `python setup.py develop` does: it installs the package (typically just a source folder) in a way that allows you to conveniently edit your code after it’s installed to the (virtual) environment, and have the changes take effect immediately.

---

**Note:** It is highly recommended to use `pip install .` (regular install) and `pip install -e .` (developer install) to install packages, as invoking `setup.py` directly will do the wrong things for many dependencies, such as pull prereleases and incompatible package versions, or make the package hard to uninstall with `pip`.

Update:

The `develop` counterpart for the latest `python -m build` approach is as follows ([as per](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#working-in-development-mode)):

[image]

Comment: Erik is right. Also useful to know is that `setup.py develop` comes with an `--uninstall` option for when you're done hacking around.

Comment: Last thought here is that another option to `setup.py develop` when hacking on a python package is to use "simple (but explicit) path modification to resolve the package properly" re [Kenneth Reitz](http://kennethreitz.org/repository-structure-and-python/)

Comment: I ran into problems using `python setup.py develop` trying to set up Ceilometer for local development. I ended up using `pip install -e PATH` (within a virtualenv) in order to avoid [problems that cropped up via `easy_install`](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/87376/unable-to-setup-ceilometer-in-develop-mode/).

Comment: not sure if this matters, but if I am using python 3 etc, does one have to run `python setup.py develop` differently?

Comment: @CharlieParker A bit late, but just python3 setup.py develop should work?

Comment: It works with python3, but don't forget to remove any current pip installation you may have, as they will clash together (it happened to me at the moment).

Comment: How to find the location of the link file that installs this? It is not in the usual place and I can not uninstall a package.

Comment: So when should someone use `pip install -e` and when `python setup.py develop`? It seems like the former is always prefered?

Comment: @yifanwu I guess when you are sure that `python setup.py develop` works reliably, and you want to avoid installing pip, like for example when quickly debugging a package on a remote machine

Comment: Hi, since "python -m build" is now recommanded over "setup.py install", should we still use the "develop" command or should we use other alternatives?

Comment: @EricBurel see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#working-in-development-mode

Answer (score 159):

From the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html). The `develop` will not install the package but it will create a `.egg-link` in the deployment directory back to the project source code directory.

So it's like installing but instead of copying to the `site-packages` it adds a symbolic link (the `.egg-link` acts as a multiplatform symbolic link).

That way you can edit the source code and see the changes directly *without* having to reinstall every time that you make a little change. This is useful when you are the developer of that project hence the name `develop`. If you are just installing someone else's package you should use `install`

Answer (score 32):

Another thing that people may find useful when using the `develop` method is the `--user` option to install without sudo. Ex:

```
python setup.py develop --user
```

instead of

```
sudo python setup.py develop
```

Comment: IIUC you should never `setup.py develop` in your system, this only makes sense in a virtualenv.

Comment: @dividebyzero Do you mean one should always use `python setup.py develop --user`, if I understand correctly? Besides, could you please tell me where the package is installed by using `python setup.py develop --user`? Thanks!

Comment: I think the `--user` will install in a directory in your home account, and will not affect other users in your system. The `develop` will make links to your project source directory instead of actually copying everything. `develop --user` should be OK, and `develop` in a virtualenv too. Only `develop` to the actual system is weird, because you may have other users using something that points to the project in your personal copy of the project source code.

Comment: Many (most?) people aren't running on multi-user systems though

Comment: I'd say most devs are running on multi-user systems.  Mac and Linux desktops are probably the majority of developers out there these days.

Comment: Where can I find a list of setup.py switches? I feel like there should be a --no-deps somewhere...

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question as asked.

Comment: @boatcoder, Mac and Linux (and Windows) might be multi-user _capable_ systems, but most likely  the developer is the only (real) user account of his desktop, and I believe that's what pastew meant.