# Installing a Python/Cython (extension) module under development

Tags: python, cython, distutils, setup.py

I am constantly working on a Python module which contains C++ extensions wrapped with Cython. The `setup.py` currently handles the building of the extension module, and is called as `python3 setup.py --build_ext --inplace`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


srcDir = "../src"
src = ["_MyProject.pyx"]    # list of source files

print("source files: {0}".format(src))

modules = [Extension("_MyProject",
                    src,
                    language = "c++",
                    extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11", "-O3", "-DNOGTEST"],
                    extra_link_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11"],
                    libraries=["MyProjectLib", "log4cxx"],
                    library_dirs=["../"])]

for e in modules:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature" : True}

setup(name="_MyProject",
     cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
     ext_modules=modules)
```

On top of the Cython module `_MyProject`, there is a pure Python module `MyProject` which imports stuff from `_MyProject`.

Currently I use and test the module by `cd`-ing into its directory and importing it from there. How do I need to modify my `setup.py` so that I can install `MyProject` into my site packages and have the package always up to date?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly I would do this using virtualenv and python setup.py develop - see http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install

Answer (score 1):

Add the argument `py_modules = ["MyProject.py",]` to your setup() function.

Comment: After doing that, how do I need to call `setup.py` to achieve the desired installation?