# Rebuilding Cython code

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I downloaded a module that uses Cython. I installed it after building the content as folows,

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

But I would like to make changes to the Cython parts of that module and recompile them. It turns out that I can't recompile the Cython files. In other words, I simply get this output when I build again,

```
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
running build_scripts
```

without any changes beinf reflected in the installation directory.

My goal is to make changes to a Cython .pyx file that is part of a large module and have it recompiled and installed after every change I make.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't"?  How did you install the module, and how did you try to recompile it?

Comment: Well, if I build, I get this
```
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
running build_scripts

```
and nothing gets changed

Comment: I built it as follows,
`python setup.py build`
and I installed it using,
`python setup.py install`

Comment: I would like to do the same build-install procedure after making changes to some of the Cython files. The changes aren't getting reflected in the installation directory when I do that.

Comment: Did you redo both the build and the install, or just the build?

Comment: Both, nothing gets changed in the installation directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `python setup.py develop`, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install).  After you make changes, do `python setup.py develop` again.