# how do you install python package without dependencies

Tags: python

I am trying to install a python module without dependencies.

I run:

```
python setup.py install
```

but this install dependencies, any ideas how could do this?

Comment: Why would you want to? They're called *"dependencies"* for a reason!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, when I run python setup.py install, it gets the dependecies but the I have the latest dependent app already installed.

Comment: Well that's useful information to put in the question. What does the module require, and what do you already have installed? Are you using `virtualenv`s?

Comment: You could use `python setup.py develop -N` (if you were ok with using `develop` instead of `install`).

Comment: @HonzaOsobne Is there an equivalent flag for `setup.py install`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using `setup.py`, you could use:

```
python setup.py develop --no-deps
```

If you're using `pip`, try:

```
pip install --no-deps
```

Comment: Why is `--no-deps` not recognised in `setup.py install`?

Comment: Please be aware that **develop and install are different** and have their own purposes.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install)  for more info