# How to setup Django package development environment?

Tags: python, django, package

I'm trying to create a library to reuse among my projects. What is the best way to setup the library package so that I don't have to add and remove my library from teh virtual_env every time I make small a change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
python setup.py develop
```

It will set up links from the folder where you are developing the code to your virtualenv.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588871/315168