# python, project structure to test separate git library

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

Suppose I have a private git repo(`A` library repo) which I want to use from my project. (`B` project repo)

I clone `A` to my `~/workspace/A`
and I work on my project at `~/workspace/B`

`B` 's virtualenv resides in `~/virtualenvs/B`

In order to modify `A` and test the modified from `B`,

1. modify `A`
2. commit push to `A`'s origin
3. pip install `A` git+http://A-repository

Which is very time consuming.. Can I reduce the above steps to

1. modify `A`

by placing A inside somewhere in project `B`'s virtualenv?

and commit & push only after I test the modified `A` from `B`?

** Edit

I could think of two ways and wonder if there's better way.

1. add `A` as a git submodule to `B` somewhere (which is in python module path) under `~/workspace/B` 
   : I just didn't like submodule whenever I used it.. hard to grasp and manage them.
2. add `~/workspace/parent-of-A/` to python-path `before` virutalenv python-path
   So when I edit `~/workspace/parent-of-A/A`, it is readily seen by `B`.
   And production server and other people who don't modify `A` could use `pip install-ed` version in virtualenv.

Comment: possible duplicate or variant of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15031694/1298153

Comment: Activate B's virtualenv, cd to A directory and `python setup.py devel` should probably work.

Comment: @m01: it requires me to create .tar.gz of the library. I hope I could avoid creating an archive to use my library.

Comment: @eugene No, it doesn't. See [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20043907/1377864). AFAIK it does the same thing as my suggestion, but using `pip`.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin: ok . but still needs a separate step before I can test the library

Comment: You do it only once. It installs package by creating a symlink to the directory, where source files are located. So all changes in source files are immidiately reflected on installed package (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19048754/1377864)).

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin oh that's precisely I'm after, let me try that.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin: so `python setup.py devlelop` seems to work great, although I'm not yet prepared to deploy the modified library and not sure how would I write the `A` into my `B` 's `requirements.pip` file so that I can deploy to other systems. (and keep my develop mode intact because I would need to keep modifying `A`) .. I'll update when I 'm ready to deploy `A`