# deleting a link in mininet

Tags: mininet, sdn

While I was looking for some way to delete a link in mininet, I came across this : https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2013-November/003270.html
I added this code snippet in net.py of the mininet module, but still when I try from the mininet console, it says mininet object has no attribute delLink, any idea why so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must reinstall mininet after you change the python code, by running 'make clean && make install'. Or you can run 'make develop' instead, and then changes to the python code will take effect immediately. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install) for more about the distinction between install and develop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
link s1 h1 down
```

and enter this command to reverse it:

```
link s1 h1 up
```

you can see the src and dst of the links via this command:

```
links
```