# install python3 project using autotools

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, autotools, automake, autogen

I have a `gtk+3` project written in `python3` with file-structure (I am in `Linux`):

```
$tree
.
├── autogen.sh
├── configure.ac
├── Makefile.am
├── mkbib.desktop.in
└── src
    ├── __init__.py       #empty file
    ├── menubar.ui
    ├── menu.py
    ├── mkbib.py
    ├── pybib.py
    └── view.py
```

the mkbib.py contains `app.run()`:

```
$tail -5 mkbib.py 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = mkbib()
    r = app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(r)
```

I am trying to create autotools as shown in [developer.gnome site](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/3.20/hello-world.py.html.en)

It looks like:

```
$cat configure.ac 
# This file is processed by autoconf to create a configure script
AC_INIT([mkbib], [1.0],[],[mkbib])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.10 no-define foreign dist-xz no-dist-gzip])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile mkbib.desktop])
AC_OUTPUT

$cat Makefile.am 
bin_SCRIPTS = mkbib
%.desktop: %.desktop.in
desktopdir = $(datadir)/applications
desktop_DATA = mkbib.desktop
dist_noinst_DATA = mkbib.desktop.in
mkbib:src/mkbib.py
```

and autogen.sh is complete copy as given in the link.

Now, If I am trying to run autogen.sh(This runs without error); make install, for make install, I am getting:

```
make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Python/Mkbib'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/var/tmp/bin'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/var/tmp/share/applications'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mkbib.desktop '/var/tmp/share/applications'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Python/Mkbib'
```

As you can see, no executable `mkbib` is created. Though, `.desktop` file is placed in proper place

How I can create a single executable using autotools?

**NB:** As per python's standard, I have also tried setup.py, but I have failed even worse with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343265/install-python-package-using-setup-py)

**LRN's Reply:**
with `bin_SCRIPTS = src/mkbib.py` I am getting:

```
$make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Python/Mkbib'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/home/rudra/.local/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c src/mkbib.py '/home/rudra/.local/bin'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/home/rudra/.local/share/applications'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mkbib.desktop '/home/rudra/.local/share/applications'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Python/Mkbib'

$/home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py 
/home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py: line 9: from: command not found
/home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `"Gtk",'
/home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py: line 10: `gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")'


$python3 /home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/.local/bin/mkbib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import menu
ImportError: No module named 'menu'
```

Comment: what happens if you use `bin_SCRIPTS = mkbib.py` ? or `bin_SCRIPTS = src/mkbib.py` ?

Comment: Do you have `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of the mkbib.py?

Comment: I access that with ` env`, but yes

Comment: I guess, I am getting this problem because mkbib.py is in bin, but other files are not placed as a python3 module