# NameError - Python errors where code doesn't exist anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using a script that an old coworker wrote.

He was using the `logging` module to print out to standard output.

(Specifically, he created a `logger` using `logging.getLogger()` and then would `logger.info("some message")`)

I swapped this out for `print` (I intend to add `logging` back later).

Now, when I run code, I get this error.
`NameError: name 'logger' is not defined`

I removed `__pycache__` but I'm still experiencing the error.

Comment: Show us all relevant code and the full error traceback.

Comment: check what line the error is in, there should be a 'logger' reference there

Comment: code is quite long, hard to just show one snippet. I'll try.
also, points to file that exists but line number has completely different code in now.

Comment: FYI, running new installation of Anaconda 3.7 distribution on new Mac.

Comment: Found that issue is Anaconda distribution and how it (the specific distribution) caches changes to a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664942/anaconda-keeps-caching-modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda keeps caching modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664942/anaconda-keeps-caching-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is Anaconda distribution and how it (the specific distribution) caches changes to a file.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664942/anaconda-keeps-caching-modules). Closing question.