# How to develop and test opensource python library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python so my question is kinda trivial. I have an open-source library that I would like to develop and contribute to.

Lets say the lib has operations A,B and C. I want to change something in, say code of A operation and test it. However, every time I execute my modified  code of the library it always tends to run the version of the lib installed with `pip`.

1. I am new to python, but how can I develop code of this lib and then run it using the code that I have actually modified? So that I can see my changes or maybe debug the execution.
2. What is the pythonic way of developing locally an OS library so that I can run it, debug it and test it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install

Comment: @PeterWood So I should use the 'pip install -e .' Could you elaborate step-by-step or in points how should such a develop env be handled for a given git clone form github? I understand that 1) clone git repo 2) do my changes to operation A form cloned repo 3)..., how can I now check how changes affects the working of the lib?