# What's the difference between 'pip3 install -e .' and 'python3 setup.py develop'

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

When installing a Python package locally in editable mode, both 'pip3 install -e .', and 'python3 setup.py develop', will both install the package locally in editable mode. I know that 'pip3 install -e .' is recommended over 'python3 setup.py develop', but I am unclear as to why and what the differences are between the two.

This answer for a separate question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048754/8903959) seems to indicate that it's because it's more difficult to uninstall when using python3 setup.py develop. Why is that the case?

Additionally, the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048754/8903959) says that dependencies are managed differently and incorrectly. What are the specific differences surrounding dependencies and why do they exist, especially if 'python3 setup.py develop' manages them incorrectly?

Apologies if this is a trivial question, but try as I might I could not find the answer or documentation for this reasoning elsewhere.

Comment: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html -- The recommendation is to not run the `setup.py` script directly anymore. `setup.py` can still exist as a configuration file, but whenever possible it should not be used as a script.

Comment: This is a really great article. While it doesn't cover exactly the specific differences it offers great reasons why to not use python3 setup.py develop and I think could serve as an answer to this question. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: At this point in time, trying to get an accurate description of the differences between python setup.py install and python -m pip install is rather pointless. -- With that said, if for some actual practical reason you really do need to know the differences in behavior for some specific aspect of these two methods, feel free to ask a new question or rephrase this current question with a more focused scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point in time, trying to get an accurate description of the differences between `python setup.py install` and `python -m pip install` seems rather pointless.

`python setup.py develop` and `python setup.py install` originate from a time before *pip* existed. The behavior of these commands has not been kept up to date with all the latest standards while *pip*'s behavior has. *setuptools*' place and role in the Python packaging ecosystem has shifted, it is now simply a "build back-end". `setup.py` should now be considered as a configuration file only, not as an executable script.

I recommend reading this article for a lot of historical and technical background on the topic: [*Why you shouldn't invoke setup.py directly*](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html).

Also this article on the *Python packaging user guide*: [*Is `setup.py` deprecated?*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/)

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies things immensly!